# Best Camera for shoot a gameplay Video

Tags: iphone

I have developed some games for iPhone and iPad but the success rate in appstore is bad. So I think I should do some marketing things and thats why I need to make some gameplay video of my games.

Can you guys please suggest me some good mid-range video camera for shooting the gameplay video? I prefer Sony/ canon.

A quick help will be appreciated.

Thanks to all

Answer (score 3):

You should use an application for this, not an actual camera.

Comment: Agreed - Recording it running in the emulator using software seems like a much more reasonable approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an application, or a camera, whichever you choose, or use both. You could use one to film you playing the game on the iPhone, then superimpose the video of gameplay on the location of the iPhone's screen, but it gets a little complicated. If you're looking for an actual camera, though, I've used a Sanyo Xacti HD1010. It's extremely competitively priced, considering it shoots in 1080I HD, and the videos are stunning quality for such a cheap and small camera.

Take a look: http://www.google.com/products/catalog?q=sanyo+xacti+hd1010&um=1&ie=UTF-8&tbm=shop&cid=9874865433190768953&sa=X&ei=xwZMTtjHCJPUiAKHyIG-Aw&ved=0CEcQ8wIwAg

Also, don't forget to watch some HD videos that show off the quality: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YREIIVL_9dk

Comment: thnak you, the camera is looking good. anyway do u know which application should I use for the video?

Comment: @hasan - Clarification: By 'application', do you mean to transfer video from the camera to the computer, or do you mean to record the iPhone without a camera?